# dropzone не хочет отправлять запрос на сервер

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
<div class="dropzone needsclick dz-clickable" id="dropZed"><div class="dz-message needsclick">
  <font>
    <font>
    Перетащите сюда файлы или нажмите , 
    </font>
  <font>чтобы загрузить. </font>
  <span class="note needsclick">
    <font>Выбранные файлы </font>
  </span>
</font></div></div><script>drop_file('admin/adress/book', 'dropZed');</script>
```

Это `js` и `html` код, не понимаю - почему не работает?
Вообще даже запроса не делает, я не вижу `привет` на обработчике.

```
function drop_file(url, id) {
    var dzone = new Dropzone("#"+id, {
        paramName: "img",
        url: root+url,
        method: "file",
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        dictResponseError: 'Server not Configured',
        success: function() {
            alert(1);
        }

    });
    dzone.on("complete", function(file) {
         myDropzone.removeFile(file);
    });
    //Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
}
```

**Обновление:**

```
if(!empty($_FILES)) {
    print_r($_FILES);
}
```

Это просто обработчик, на котором пытаюсь поймать массив, но он не приходит туда, даже просто `echo 'ПРИВЕТ';` не вижу.

Comment: А что в консоли происходит? есть запрос и ошибки вообще? `root` какой?

Comment: Нету ошибок в консоли ни каких. Но не суть я уже сделал посредством jquery upload file... Там всё есть и загружает всё, в общем всё окей, вот только какой то прикол после загрузки вроде бы возвращаю Json но он мне выдаёт вот такую ошибку, не в консоли, а сам скрипт выдаёт.... SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0